# iphoto effect over thumbnails?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need to implement an "iphoto effect" over thumbnails.

When the mouse moves over an image all the images in that gallery should appear in sequence.

If I click on it a lightbox with a slideshow sequence starts.

(I know how to do the lightbox, I dunno how to make the iphoto effect. Is there any module there for it ?)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a module for it. You could create this effect with JavaScript, but you would need to have the images loaded to make the effect smooth.

You would need to track the mouse movement hovering over the image. It would probably be a bit tricky to do but not. Impossible.

A good solution would probably be to use z-index to decide which img to show.

Comment: ok, I can do it with javascript, however I need to load all images first. With which CCK field I should start to implement my javascript code ?